# JavaScript error: Uncaught ReferenceError: userNumber is not defined on line 43

Tags: jquery, reference, javascript

I am creating a JavaScript guessing game. I have set up the functions. I keep on receiving an error.

> JavaScript error: Uncaught ReferenceError: userNumber is not defined on line 43.

I am running my code through this online interpreter: it has all the code I am running.
http://js.do/seacode/30269

I am passing the `userNumber` into the function `guessingNumber()` but it is not passing the variable into it.

Code:

```
<script>
// Ask user to enter guess
function playGame() {
    var play = prompt("Would you like to play? ( Type: (y) or (n) )");
    if (play === 'y') {
        var userNumber = prompt("Enter your guess (1 - 100)");
    } else if (play === 'n') {
        prompt("Come Again!");
    } else {
        prompt("Enter a valid choice ");
    }
}

// Generate the random number
function createRandNum(play) {
    if (play === 'y') {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    };
}

// Evaluate whether the number is correct
function guessingNumber(userNumber) {
    if (userNumber !== randomNumber) {
        if (userNumber < randomNumber) {
            console.log("Number too low.");
        } else if (userNumber > randomNumber) {
            console.log("Number too high.");
        }
    }
    if (userNumber === randomNumber) {
        console.log("It's a match.");
    }
}

// Display results
function displayResults(userNumber, randomNumber) {
    console.log("The number you chose was " + userNumber);
    console.log("The number the computer generated was " + randomNumber);
}

playGame();
createRandNum(playGame);
guessingNumber(userNumber);
displayResults(userNumber, randomNumber);

</script>
```

Comment: `userNumber` is undefined... Provide relevant code in question, not on external website

Comment: Look up "JavaScript variable scope" if you're not familiar with lexical scoping.

Comment: Specifically its not defined here; guessingNumber(userNumber);

Comment: you are defining userNumber in playGame function's scope. If you remove `var` when declaring variable, variable will be set on global scope

Comment: You define `userNumber` locally to the functions, but you use it as a global variable when you call `guessingNumber` and `displayResults`.

Comment: You're calling several variables within functions that are local variables - in that they're contained only within the function where they're defined. You'll need to use `return` on these functions in order to chain them and retrieve/pass on the result from each.

Comment: Thanks. and all these down votes are gonna get me off the chat rooms smh nor can i up vote answers

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the userNumber variable inside the playGame function.  It is not visible outside that function.  If you put this line at the beginning of your script:

var userNumber;

and remove the var keyword from the line where you display the prompt, I think you will be all set.

Comment: He won't be all set. He has a similar problem with `randomNumber`.

Comment: Thanks, i also had to define randomNumber globally, but i get no output.

Comment: The tool you are using doesn't produce output from console.log.  You have to use document.write instead.  Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the userNumber Variable just exist in the local function playGame(), you must declare this variable in a global scope.

```
<script>

// Ask user to enter guess
//Declare the global variable to use in others function
var userNumber;
function playGame() {
    var play = prompt("Would you like to play? ( Type: (y) or (n) )");
    if (play === 'y') {
        //Getting the value, this value will be defined 
        userNumber = prompt("Enter your guess (1 - 100)");
    } else if (play === 'n') {
        prompt("Come Again!");
    } else {
        prompt("Enter a valid choice ");
    }
}

................

</script>
```

I hope that this answer help you...!!